# Override named color then restore it

Tags: color, environments

I'm trying to figure out how to override a color for a portion of an environment, restoring it to its former value thereafter. I have this (only the relevant code included here):

```
\newenvironment*{foo}
{
    \colorlet{colorsave}{bar}
    \definecolor{bar}{RGB}{100,100,100}

    % some stuff that relies on the bar color being overridden

    % restore the bar color to its former value (this is the part I don't know how to do)
    \definecolor{bar}{RGB}{colorsave}

    % some stuff that relies on the bar color being restored to its former value
}
{
}
```

This does not compile. Best I can tell from my lengthy log, the root cause is:

```
Bla.tex:207: LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 199 ended 
by \end{sidebar}.
! Emergency stop
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

If I leave the `\definecolor` out, I can see that it correctly overrides the color, so that part is working. It's the restoration that has me stumped.

Note that I can not rely on the color being restore after the environment completes, because part of my environment relies on it being restored. It's a sidebar. I need to override the color for the title of the sidebar, then restore it for the body.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you should just be able to use definecolor it's a local declaration anyway so you do not need to restore anything, it will reset at end of the environment, but if asking about an error please always show the error message from the log "does not compile" is not so helpful, and also provide a test file that allows people to debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added what I could find in my log. I've also added an explanation as to why I can't rely on the color being restored when the environment ends.

Comment: There is still no usable test file (and no indication that the  error is related to color) but I would assume that if you saved the color with `\colorlet{colorsave}{bar}` you can put it back with `\colorlet{bar}{colorsave}` (note this is xcolor package syntax not color)

Comment: If it should affect only a part of your environment, enclose this part in `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. This keeps the changes local and you don't have to bother abut restoration.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle urg, that seems so obvious in hindsight. Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can restore via

```
\colorlet{bar}{colorsave}
```